# Deallocating 2D array and creating in function C

Tags: c

I have a function "n" which create a 2D array. In `main()` function I call this function with key "n". If function "n" has been already called it must deallocate array (`p_spz`) and run function "n" and create array again. My code:

```
if ((p_file != NULL) && (p_spz == NULL) && (funkcia == 'n'))
{
    p_spz = n(p_file);
}
else if ((p_file != NULL) && (p_spz != NULL) && (funkcia == 'n'))
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        free(p_spz[i]);
    }
    free(p_spz);
    p_spz = n(p_file);
}
```

After first function n is everything OK but second time program failed. How to deallocate it properly?
Here is "n" function.

```
char** n(FILE *p_file) {
    int poc = 0, i = 1, j = 0, l, k=0;
    char ch;
    while (!feof(p_file)) {
        ch = fgetc(p_file);
        if (ch == '\n') {
            poc++;
        }
    }
    poc = poc / 5;
    char **p_spz = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*poc);
    fseek(p_file, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    char riadok[50];
    while (fgets(riadok, sizeof(riadok), p_file)) {
        if (i == 2) {
            p_spz[k] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 7);
            for (l = 0; l < 7; l++) {
                p_spz[k][l] = riadok[l];
            }
            p_spz[k][7] = 0;
            k++;
        }
        else if (i == 5) {
            i = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    fseek(p_file, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    return p_spz;
}
```

It reads a file (file is open, in function above this function). It reads second and then every fifth line. Then it writes this string into array.
Everything is working properly until I want to deallocate array.

Comment: `nullptr`? In C?

Comment: Where is the definition of your function `n()` ? And did you mean `NULL` in place of `nullptr`? Or is it C++?

Comment: @J...S n() function is added.

Comment: The occurrences of 7 and 5 in function `n()` are mysterious.  Using 50 for the line length isn't all that sensible — lines can be a lot longer than that, in general.  Maybe it isn't a problem for the data you'll be processing; just be cautious.  (I'd use 4096 as a starting point, or POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)
to avoid line length limits altogether.)

Comment: Your criterion could probably be better represented by `if (i % 5 == 2)`.  You have major issues with `p_spz[k] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 7);
            …
            p_spz[k][7] = 0;` — you allocate seven bytes and trample over the eighth.  You might or might not run into actual problems, but the behaviour is profoundly undefined (and therefore best avoided).

Comment: I know that length of line is max 50 characters.

Comment: The line length includes the newline and the terminal null, so there are no more than 48 other characters per line?  You may well be OK, as long as you trust your data source.  If you might have to deal with hostile users (anybody who isn't you), be cautious.